# alternate method of onRequestPermissionResult() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am requesting runtime permissions in Flutter. How to handle the result of permissions in Flutter. As we know In Android there is onRequestPermissionsResult(). Whats alternate method in Flutter.

Comment: You may want to give a try to [permission_handler](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler) package. Or handle the things using `MethodChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

use the plugin [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions)

It can check, request and get permissions with callbacks

Sample code from the example

```
requestPermission() async {
    final res = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(permission);
    print("permission request result is " + res.toString());
  }

  checkPermission() async {
    bool res = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission);
    print("permission is " + res.toString());
  }

  getPermissionStatus() async {
    final res = await SimplePermissions.getPermissionStatus(permission);
    print("permission status is " + res.toString());
  }
```

Comment: I am using 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission
 for run time permission.....